# Quais são as diferenças entre HashMap e Hashtable?

Tags: java, hashmap, coleção

Quais são as diferenças entre `HashMap` e `Hashtable` em Java?

Qual é mais eficiente?

Comment: Resumindo em um linha: A HashTable é sincronizada(thread-safe). O HashMap, não.

Comment: Consequentemente, se for uma situação sem concorrência, em que tanto faz usar uma ou outra, a versão não-sincronizada (HashMap) será mais eficiente.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Hashmap

- Não é sincronizada
- Aceita valores nulos e uma chave nula
- É possível varrer toda estrutura com um iterador de forma simples
- Possui `containsValue()` e `containsKey()`
- É mais rápida
- Consome menos memória
- Mais moderna
- Mãe: `AbstractMap`

## Hashtable

- Sincronizada e pode ser facilmente usada em ambiente concorrente
- Não aceita nulos
- Iterar é mais complicado
- Possui `contains()`
- Tem *overhead* pela sincronização
- Ocupa mais memória
- Considerada obsoleta
- Mãe: `Dictionary`

Retirei a informação principalmente [dessa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40878/221800).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).